# Can we vote to rename chat?

Tags: discussion, design, chat

"Salesforce" is kind of a lame name for the default chat room.  Let's make this something more interesting!

Vote for your favorite(s) below, or add a new one.

Comment: I strongly suspect the reason for the lack of enthusiasm in response to your question is that the chat room is rarely used. Since a link to it is no longer prominently displayed in the UI, just finding it to begin with (or remembering that its there), can be something of a challenge if you don't already know where to find it. Ever since the link was hidden, I've tended to forget that it even exists to drop in and socialize if anyone is around.

Comment: I cannot see your problem with the name being long? The simple fact is there is a clear lack of people using the chat - if as @crmprogdev has discussed, that chat is placed on the main menu, then more people will be able to easily access the chat rooms. For example, look at the StackOverflow chat rooms - they are widely used, and some of the chat room names are very long ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Cloud Chat**

A reference to "the Salesforce cloud".

Answer (score 0):

**No Software, Just Chat**

A spoof on the "No Software" slogan.

Answer (score 0):

**ChatForce**

surely there are better ideas out there.